# Neural Network doesn't work in XOR gate test

Tags: neural-network, c++17

I am trying to use c++ to implement supervised machine learning. And I am using XOR to test whether the network is working or not. But, it doesn't work. The error does converge but when I use the same inputs to predict the outputs, those are not as expected.

intput : [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

expected output : [[0], [1], [1], [0]]

layer : 2 -> 2 -> 1 ;Learning rate : 0.1 ;activation functions : sigmoid

I have figured out that there is no typo/math problem in forward propagate and I think there may have some problems in back propagation.

Here is my back propagation function:

```
    void BackPropagate(){
    if (label_set.empty()) {
        printf("You Need To Set Up Your Labels First! (Call : \"SetLabel(...)\")\n");
        return;
    }

    unsigned int last_layer = layer_size - 1;
    // back prop of last layer
    for (unsigned int neu = 0; neu < neurons[last_layer].size(); ++neu){
        vector<double> y_sub = subtract(neurons[last_layer][neu].activated_output, transpose(label_set)[neu]); //(ŷ - y)
        vector<double> dacti_a; dacti_a.reserve(training_set_size);  // dsigmoid( sum_product_output )
        for (double value : neurons[last_layer][neu].output)
            dacti_a.push_back(deri_active(value, neurons[last_layer][neu].act_fcn));

        neurons[last_layer][neu].delta = multiply(y_sub, dacti_a);  // update delta

        // update weight and bias
        neurons[last_layer][neu].bias -= learning_rate * sum(neurons[last_layer][neu].delta);
        for (unsigned pren = 0; pren < connections[last_layer][neu].size(); ++pren) {
            connections[last_layer][neu][pren].weight -= learning_rate *sum(
                    multiply(neurons[last_layer][neu].delta,neurons[last_layer - 1][pren].output));
        }
    }

    // back prop of hidden layers
    for (unsigned int layer = last_layer - 1; layer > 0; --layer){
        for (unsigned int neu = 0; neu < neurons[layer].size(); ++neu){
            vector<double> weight_delta = multiply(neurons[layer + 1][0].delta,
                                                   vector<double>(), connections[layer+1][0][neu].weight);  // sum(weight*delta)

            for (unsigned int posn = 1; posn < neurons[layer+1].size(); ++posn)
                weight_delta = addition(weight_delta,
                        multiply(neurons[layer+1][posn].delta, vector<double>(), connections[layer+1][posn][neu].weight));

            vector<double> dsig_a; dsig_a.reserve(training_set_size);  // dsigmoid( sum_product_output )
            for (double value : neurons[layer][neu].output)
                dsig_a.push_back(deri_active(value, neurons[layer][neu].act_fcn));

            neurons[layer][neu].delta = multiply(weight_delta, dsig_a);  // update delta

            // update weight and bias
            neurons[layer][neu].bias -= learning_rate * sum(neurons[layer][neu].delta);
            for (unsigned pren = 0; pren < connections[layer][neu].size(); ++pren)
                connections[layer][neu][pren].weight -= learning_rate *
                        sum(multiply(neurons[layer][neu].delta, neurons[layer-1][pren].output));
        }
    }

}
```

FYI, Here is my full code : https://github.com/samuel8876170/NeuralNetwork

Anyone can give me some suggestions for debugging this?

Update(26Dec,2019): I have found the solution to get the correct results of XOR gate and others (OR/AND gate) which is increasing the layer of the network to 2->2->2->1 then solved. But what are the possible reasons that my network need 3 layers to get the expected results but on the internet, most only need 2 layers?